# Ensure a string representing a decimal number has a 0 before the "."

Tags: c#, string

I have a string variable in C# that will be  a  'single' data type number in string format like '.11' or '0.11' or '12.11 etc.

**My question:** I need to pad the above string with a leading '0' if no digits have been specified before the decimal in the above variable. How would I do this in C# in the most efficient manner? So if the variable is '12.11' then no padding is needed.

```
string newValue = null;
string searchFieldValue1 = ".11";
//set new value according to this logic: pad it with a leading 0 so its 0.11
```

Comment: If it's going into a `Single` are you sure you really need to pad it at all? After all, it won't make any difference once it's been parsed to `Single`.

Comment: I have some logic in a class, where I need convert a ".11" to  "0.11". Its not related to single data type but just is coincidentally a string representation of a single number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newValue = searchFieldValue1.StartsWith(".")
               ? "0" + searchFieldValue1
               : searchFieldValue1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test if the first character is a `'.'`:

```
string searchFieldValue1 = ".11";
string newValue = searchFieldValue1;
if (newValue[0] == '.')
   newValue = "0" + newValue;
```

Or using the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
string searchFieldValue1 = ".11";
string newValue = (searchFieldValue1[0] == '.' ? "" : "0") + searchFieldValue1;
```

But probably the best method is to simply parse the string as a number, then convert it back to a string with the correct formatting (see [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details):

```
string searchFieldValue1 = ".11";
string newValue = float.Parse(searchFieldValue1).ToString("0.00");
```

This method will also remove unnecessary leading zeros and ensure that the result has exactly 2 digits after the decimal (e.g. `001` → `1.00`)